# How to naturally roll-over to the next day when adding hours to a datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have some code that needs to quantize dates read in from file.  For example, setting 11:50 to 12:00 to clean up the numbers.  I currently do this with something like the following:

```
end = end.replace(hour = end.hour + 1, minute = 0)
```

You then run into a problem if the `end.hour` is 11 PM, since this will roll over to the next day.  You can guard against this with code like...

```
if end.hour == 23:
    end = end.replace(day = end.day + 1, hour = 0, minute = 0)
else:
    end = end.replace(hour= end.hour + 1, minute=0)
```

But then what if that day is the last day of the month? Then you will need to roll over to the next month, and so forth.

There must be a cleaner way to do this.  How do you handle quantizing dates while accounting for rolling to the next day/month/year?

Comment: Check out `datetime`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: @pyStarter: judging by the use of the `.replace()` method the OP *already* is using the `datetime` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use `datetime.replace()`, use a [`timedelta()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta), adding in to your `datetime` object:

```
end += timedelta(hours=1)
```

This'll take care of rolling over the date for you:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> end = datetime(2014, 9, 1, 22, 45)
>>> end += timedelta(hours=1)
>>> end
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 1, 23, 45)
>>> end += timedelta(hours=1)
>>> end
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 2, 0, 45)
```

This applies to incrementing the month and year too, of course:

```
>>> last_day = datetime(2014, 12, 31, 23, 45)
>>> last_day + timedelta(hours=1)
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 45)
```

Answer (score 1):

To round to the next hour (so the minutes=0) you could use [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil) like this:

```
import datetime as DT
import dateutil.rrule as rrule

def next_hour(date):
    rr = rrule.rrule(rrule.HOURLY, byminute=[0], dtstart=date, count=1)
    return rr.after(date, inc=True)

print(next_hour(DT.datetime(2000,1,31,11,50)))    
# 2000-01-31 12:00:00

print(next_hour(DT.datetime(2000,1,31,12,0)))    
# 2000-01-31 12:00:00

print(next_hour(DT.datetime(2000,1,31,23,50)))    
# 2000-02-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: @Martijn: The OP asked how to round 11:50 to 12:00. Adding a `timedelta(hours=1)` to the datetime will not suffice. Presumably, the OP also wants 12:00 to remain 12:00. So I don't think dateutil is overkill. We are interpreting the question differently.